# Show about a man who is held prisoner in a secret place where very peculiar things happen

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember there was a Simpsons episode that mocked it, I don't know what episode or what season. I do know the show aired in the 60's or 70's.

It's basic premise is:

- A man, probably a spy, was captured and help on this island that has peculiar things on it.
- The people also held on the island all dress in turn of the century clothing or something similar
- There's giant bubbles that go around catching/killing people
- All the captives are known as a number and I think the ultimate point of the show was to find out who number 1 was
- I just remember that the show was very strange and not much of it made sense and it wasn't supposed to

Comment: I found out it was Season 10, ep 6 of the Simpsons.

Comment: Actually it was season **12**, episode 6. I will update the answer.

Comment: You are perfectly correct that it was very strange and did'nt make much sense. Which was fabulous.

Comment: There was an updated version done a few years ago.  It was not as good as the original but still had some interesting ideas.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's [The Prisoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner).

To answer the points you raise:

1. The man was a British agent, presumably a spy.
2. They did wear [peculiar clothes](http://www.fanboy.com/archive-images/prisoner-tv-series.jpg), but this was the 60s! :)
3. The [giant bubbles](http://www.dvdoutsider.co.uk/articles/pics/p/prisoner4.jpg) were there to stop people escaping.
4. The main character was known as Number Six. His main contact was Number Two (the  person who was Number Two varied frequently). Part of the mystery was working out who Number One was.
5. Indeed, it did not make a lot of sense and the [final episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_Out_%28The_Prisoner%29) generated a lot of controversy by leaving many questions unanswered.

However, it did produce [some memorable quotes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061287/quotes), including: **"I am not a number, I am a free man!"**

**Update:** The Simpsons episode is [The Computer Wore Menace Shoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Computer_Wore_Menace_Shoes), season 12 episode 6.

Comment: The giant bubble was called "Rover" (and there appears to have only been one). Also, you can see where it was filmed, if in the right area [Portmeirion](http://www.portmeirion-village.com/) is certainly worth a visit.

Comment: I think you could give better examples of the "peculiar clothes" than that - like [this one](http://blog.ajchristian.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/the-prisoner-nice-clothes.jpg) for example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: disagree, I find them rather *dapper*. :) Joke - good link!

Comment: "I am not a number, I am a free man!" - listen to Iron Maiden - the prisoner: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Tb8Jo11uGo

Comment: I remember seeing - in one episode - 3 bubbles at the same time.

Comment: The guard bubble Rover also very briefly shows up in *another* Simpsons episode, S9E13, "The Joy of Sect", when Marge escapes a cult compound.

Comment: "What do you want?" "Information." "You won't get it." "By hook or by crook, we will."

Comment: “I will not be pushed, filed, stamped, indexed, briefed, debriefed or numbered!  My life is my own.”

Comment: “Be seeing you…”